Is a unitary representation of a group $G$ on $L^2 (M,\mu ,\mathcal{E})$ irreducible if $M$ is homogeneous?
Let $T:G\to GL(L^2 (M,\mu ,\mathcal{E}))$ be a representation of $G$ in $L^2 (M,\mu ,\mathcal{E})$ where $M=G/H$ is a (finite dimensional) homogeneous space ($H$ is a closed subgroup), $\mu$ is a quasi $G$-invariant measure, and $\mathcal{E}$ is a finite dimensional complex Hilbert space. If $T$ is a unitary representation, then $T$ is irreducible?

I don't think so. If you take $G=(\mathbb{R},+)$, $H=1$ and $\mathcal{E}=\mathbb{C}$, then $T$ is the translation action on $L^{2}(R)$. In this case, $T$ is unitary but not irreducible.
